# How can interfaces be comparable and at the same time functions not?

Tags: go

I have the following code-snippet:

```
type F func()

type I interface {}

func A() {}

func B() {}

func test() {
    var a interface{} = A
    var b interface{} = B
    if A == B { // 1. Compile error 
        // Code
    }

    if a == b { // 2. No compile error
        // Code
    }
}
```

If functions are not comparable and interfaces are comparable, why can I assign a function to an interface type?

--

To clarify my question another code-snippet:

```
type I interface {
    DoSomething()
}

type F func()

func (f F) DoSomething() {
    f()
}

func A() {
    fmt.Println("A")
}

func B() {
    fmt.Println("B")
}

func test() {
    var _a F = A
    var _b F = B
    var a I = _a
    var b I = _b

    if a == b { // 2. No compile error but panic
        // Code
    }
}
```

It seems to me, that I can break the type system with simple assignments.

I do not propose that functions should be comparable. My questions are:

- Why interfaces are comparable by default?
- Why is it not possible to mark an interface as comparable resp. not comparable?
- Why is it not possible do define user defined-equality?
- What is the motivation in this language design?

Comment: Because assignability and comparability are different concepts?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I think in a statically typed language assignability and comparability are related topics. I will edit my question to clarify this.

Comment: Your updated questions are very broad design questions about a language and do not qualify for SO. If you are interested in the historic context and original motivations you should ask e.g. on golang-nuts.

Comment: Thanks. I will repost it there.

Answer (score 5):

This is simply how the language is defined. From the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators):

> Interface values are comparable. Two interface values are equal if they have identical dynamic types and equal dynamic values or if both have value `nil`.

> A comparison of two interface values with identical dynamic types causes a run-time panic if values of that type are not comparable.

> function values are not comparable. However, as a special case, a [...] function value may be compared to the predeclared identifier `nil`.

That explains why the first `if` statement in your example fails at compile time, and why the second one fails at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

To cite [Ian Lance Taylor's message](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/fdePnbiZe-A/egf26yPaBwAJ)
from [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/fdePnbiZe-A/discussion) on the Go mailing list:

> On Wed, Nov 23, 2016 at 7:00 AM, T L  wrote:
>
> > On Wednesday, November 23, 2016 at 10:35:59 PM UTC+8, Axel Wagner wrote:
> >
> > > So, your suggestion is, to have functions be comparable, but have the 
> > >       comparisons always be false (unless compared to nil)? How would that be 
> > >       useful and *not* completely confusing? e.g. how would that not lead to 
> > >       people asking here, once a week, why (`os.Open == os.Open) == false` or 
> > >       something like that?
> >
> > No, I don't `os.Open != os.Open`, they are the same question, so they are 
> >     equal.
>
> Even this seemingly simple statement is unclear.  Go now supports 
>   `-buildmode=shared` and `-linkshared`, meaning that a Go program can link  against a set of shared libraries that are themselves written in Go. 
>   When running in this mode, a function like `os.Open` can easily appear 
>   multiple times in a single program image, in different shared 
>   libraries.  So while `os.Open == os.Open` might reasonably always be 
>   true, given
>
> ```
> func F() func(string) (*os.File, error) { 
>     return os.Open 
> }
> ```
>
> then it is much less clear whether
>
> ```
> F() == os.Open
> ```
>
> should be true, as `F` might be in a shared library and might return a 
>   pointer to a different instance of `os.Open`.

And that's just one of the reasons.
See another one—regarding the function values which are closures
with *the same code* but closed over *different variables—*
[explained in that same thread by Jesper Louis Andersen](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/fdePnbiZe-A/K74JBT8rCAAJ).

I would add that the whole thread is worth thorough reading and absorbing.